# python keyboard.press not working with other applicatons

Tags: python, windows

I have made a python script that presses space once a second so I can go AFK in games and not get kicked for being idle. I tested it in notepad and it works but when i open Minecraft or Roblox nothing happens.
I did try looking for an answer but couldn't find anything

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time
keyboard = Controller()


while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard.press(' ')
    keyboard.release(' ')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes games won't recognize a super-short key press.  You essentially have a space press of less than a microseconds.  Try adding a delay between the press and release.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time
keyboard = Controller()


while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard.press(' ')
    time.sleep(0.15)
    keyboard.release(' ')
```

Comment: This worked for most keys but the arrow keys still didn't work for which I had to use https://github.com/learncodebygaming/pydirectinput

Answer (score 0):

you should probably run the cmd as administrator and put in some delay for keys to be registered. play around with the values of the delay to find one that suits your need

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time
import keyboard
keyboard = Controller()


while 1:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('r'):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            keyboard.press('space')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).